# What is the gain in a non-inverting amplifier

Tags: operational-amplifier, gain, non-inverting

I am unsure if I am tackling this problem correctly. The input signal is connected to terminal E4 and the output signal is observed at terminal E9

[image]

1. What is the voltage gain when E1 is connected?
2. What is the voltage gain when E2 is connected?
3. Neither E1 or E2 is connected. What is the expected voltage gain?

**My solution:**

1. Use the formula: $$A_v = 1 + R_2/R_1$$ which then becomes: $$A_v=1+R_{FB}/R_1$$
2. Use the same formula, now just substitute R1 with R2.

$$A_v = 1+ R_{FB}/R_2$$

3. My guess is that there is no there would be no voltage gain, since there are no resistance on the top half of the circuit?

Am I totally wrong here?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by connected...? (Connected to what?)

Comment: I have edited the question. The problem specifically says "What is the gain when E1 is connected to E5?"

Comment: Yes, you are wrong and very confused.

Comment: A complicated scenario with optional  sources can be corrected by choosing  the same impedance ratio  on both Vin+ and Vin- to get a unity gain amplifier. Otherwise it is not.  i.e. Rfb/Rin- = Ref/Rin+

Comment: Your solution is arbitrary.

Comment: What do you mean with arbitrary? Can you clarify?

Comment: You are missing something E4 is not mentioned in the  3 questions yet no input is stated.  Ambiguious.

Comment: E4 is the input.  What is the gain for E9/E4 given the specified connections in the individual subproblems?  I think he's right, although I don't know why he involves R2 in the first step of part 1, or why that first step exists at all; and he could be clearer about stating "since there are no resistance on the top half of the circuit" by which I assume he means R1 and R2 have no effect since they're both open.  I agree with his answers, though.

Comment: I confirmed it with my professor today, and he told me it was correct. I don't know what your problems are though "Marko Bursic", "Chu", "Tony Stewart".

Comment: Many members have the knowledge that goes beyond your professor. In your circuit is not clear what it has to do. You can answer your question yourself by prove, inserting the signal source and then you simulate your circuit in some simulator.

Comment: I agree that people on here certainly have a lot of knowledge. I just don't understand why you had to make me doubt my answers telling me "you are wrong and very confused" while simultaneously not providing me with any sort of help or guidance.

Comment: Because your formulas are valid if E1 or E2 is connected to ground. In your case the connecting scheme just make no sense, there is nothing useful in real world, not even in theory, so this makes a lot of confusion and nobody is giving an answer, further the schematics is not complete it has a missing input signal source.

Comment: Gain is a product of multiple inputs +/- with R Ratios and offset (2.5V) But where are your inputs?  Not in the 3 questions and E4 is an illogical choice for a differential input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my interpretation of the OP's question and explanations (I have considered the simple case of connecting to ground):

- "The input signal is connected to terminal E4" means "The input signal is **directly connected** to terminal E4". So R3, Rref, Vref, E3 and E5 (if only not connected to ground) do not play any role in forming the voltage of the non-inverting input; it is determined only by the input voltage source connected to E4.
- "What is the voltage gain when E1 is connected?" means "What is the voltage gain when E1 is connected **to ground**?" So, the circuit is a non-inverting amplifier consisting of R1, RFB and the op-amp... and the OP's formula is correct.
- "What is the voltage gain when E2 is connected?" means "What is the voltage gain when E2 is connected **to ground**?" So, again the circuit is a non-inverting amplifier now consisting of R2, RFB and the op-amp... and again the OP's formula is correct.
- "Neither E1 or E2 is connected." means "Both E1 and E2 are **not grounded**". Then the circuit is simply a voltage follower where RFB does not play any significant role. So,
- "My guess is that there is no there would be no voltage gain, since there are no resistance on the top half of the circuit?" means "My guess is that there would be voltage gain of one, since there is no grounded resistance (neither R1 nor R2) on the input of the circuit?"

The purpose of the professor's test is probably to determine whether

- OP knows what the difference between the *op-amp non-inverting amplifier* and *op-amp follower* is;
- OP understands what is *ideal* and what *real* voltage source... and what is the resultant voltage when they are connected in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

The meaning of "connection" here is that there's a voltage source connected to the named node. I mean an ideal voltage source. Zero impedance and so on. You must also assume that other nodes have no external connections, with exception of E5. And the **op amp is ideal**: the inputs have infinite impedance (and thus no parasitic capacitance either).

You'll notice that it doesn't matter *what* is the voltage of that source, as long as the op-amp remains within its input and output voltage range limits based on the 5V power supply. Since no details are given about the op-amp, its assumed ideal and thus the input voltage range is 0-5V, same for output, and the output impedance is zero.

And this assumption must hold since you are not told *what* voltage is connected into E1 or E2. That's how the language of such problem is meant to be understood. If the author of the problem meant something else, they'd be of line pretty much and purposefully obfuscating.

> Neither E1 or E2 is connected. What is the expected voltage gain?

R1 and R2 are not in circuit. RFB configures the op-amp as a voltage follower. The inverting input impedance is infinite in the ideal op-amp, so the resistance of RFB is irrelevant and we replace it with a short. Gain is exactly 1.

> What is the voltage gain when E1 is connected?
> What is the voltage gain when E2 is connected?

You got things right for those cases.